# Form won't retain local variables after validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonb

I have a Form that contains an iteration over an Array of Hashes:

```
<% @user.profile["addresses"].each_with_index do |(k,v), i| %>
    <%= render partial: 'users/form/addresses_fields', locals: { f: f, i: i } %>
<% end %>
```

Note that I'm not passing k and v through locals because I'm using form helper tags instead, and I only need to use the index, for example:

```
<%= label_tag "user[profile][addresses]["+i.to_s+"][street]", "Street" %>
<%= text_field_tag "user[profile][addresses]["+i.to_s+"][street]" %>
```

Upon submit, whenever the validation fails, and the controller re renders the view, I have a `Name Error` which says `undefined local variable or method 'i' for #<#<Class:0x007fc53e26b690>:0x007fc53f5ba688>`

**Does this mean that Rails doesn't take in consideration embed or locally defined variables when re rendering views after validations fail?**

I've also tried defining variables in the view like `<% i = 0 %>` and then incrementing with each iteration, and the problem of course persist, as now I'm sure that what is the problem.

Other considerations: every field that the user fills is retaining **perfectly fine** upon validation fail, the problem is with local variables, in this case, the index of the `each_with_index`

**How can I overcome this issue?** `user.profile` is a JSONB datatype column.

I'm sure that this is or will be a common issue since now more people are using JSON and JSONB datatype columns to handle their nested attributes of a model without having to build several other models.

> Other relevant code:

**Controller:**

```
def update
  if @user.custom_update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Updated!"
    redirect_to current_user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

**Model method:**

```
def custom_update_attributes(params)
    name = params["profile"]["name"]
    gender = params["profile"]["gender"]
    birthday = params["profile"]["birthday"]
    phone = params["profile"]["phone"]
    addresses = params["profile"]["addresses"]

    self.profile["name"] = name
    self.profile["gender"] = gender
    self.profile["birthday"] = birthday
    self.profile["phone"] = phone

    #addresses
    updated_addresses = {}
    i = 0
    unless addresses.blank?
      addresses.each do |key, val|
        if val["_destroy"] == "1"
          #pass
        else
          #add
          updated_addresses[i] = val.except("_destroy")
          i = i + 1
        end
      end
    end
    self.profile["addresses"] = updated_addresses

    self.profile_will_change!
    self.save
  end
```

> I think I found what's happening using BYEBUG gem:

The line of code that is failing is the following:

```
<%= text_field_tag "user[profile][addresses]["+i.to_s+"][street]", @user.profile["addresses"][i.to_s]["street"] %>
```

When the page initially loads the form, that line of code works perfectly fine. But, if the validation fails, `[i.to_s]` from `@user.profile["addresses"][i.to_s]["street"]` gets undefined, and if I change it to `[i]` without converting it to string, the page with the errors of the validation loads perfectly fine!

I think it's just a problem with how Rails handles Array of Hashes, because at first its considering each index of the Array as the key of the sub-hash, and then when validation fails, it considers each index as an index number of the Array, not a key anymore (not a string). Weird.

Comment: Please post your controller method

Comment: @Gaston updated with controller method

Comment: @Gaston the controller and model method is working perfectly fine upon validation success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, I just added the following before any of the form's inputs:

```
<% if @user.profile["addresses"][i.to_s] != nil %>
  <% i = i.to_s %>
<% else %>
  <% i = i %>
<% end %>
```